# Can anyone provide a sed or awk way to delete last two columns for the csv file?

Tags: awk, sed

**Edit**:
**Hello all, thanks for your reply.
My question is not how to solve the sample.csv I provided here, the situation is I have more than 100 similar files, and I hope I can solve them all fast and efficiently, I solved the problem by python, but I prefere sed, because I know that sed can modify the file directly. i dont want to run the similar commands hundreds times...**

I have files generated daily, around 4 month, for each file it contains 9 columns, and now I want to remove the **last two columns** from all those files.

I was planning to use `sed` to delete the last 2 columns with `-i`, my purpose is that i can modify all files directly and dont need to write into new files. Unfortunately, I cannot find a way to do so, then I wrote my python script to finish all work.Here's my code:

```
    def remove_last_two_columns(input_dir, output_dir, file_name):
    writer = open(output_dir + file_name, "w")
    with open(input_dir + file_name, "r") as inputs:
        for line in inputs:
            parts = line.strip().split(",")
            outline = ""
            for index, part in enumerate(parts):
                if index < 7:
                    outline += "," + part

            writer.write(outline[1:] + "\n")
    writer.close()

remove_last_two_columns("/home/haifzhan/input/", "/home/haifzhan/output/", "sample.csv")
```

input:

```
C1,C2,2014-06-30 13:11:46,2014-07-01 00:19:12,43,N,N,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 13:37:40,N,N,N,N,2014-07-01 00:37:22,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 15:35:40,2014-07-01 00:23:14,36,N,N,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 16:54:07,2014-07-01 00:08:38,35,N,N,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 17:13:33,N,N,N,N,2014-07-01 00:25:55,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 17:23:05,N,N,2014-07-01 00:26:03,13,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 17:49:59,2014-07-01 02:46:20,11,N,N,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 18:16:51,2014-07-01 06:15:25,20,N,N,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 18:18:07,N,N,2014-07-01 00:02:22,24,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 18:41:27,N,N,N,N,2014-07-01 00:52:22,N



my output:
C1,C2,2014-06-30 13:11:46,2014-07-01 00:19:12,43,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 13:37:40,N,N,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 15:35:40,2014-07-01 00:23:14,36,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 16:54:07,2014-07-01 00:08:38,35,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 17:13:33,N,N,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 17:23:05,N,N,2014-07-01 00:26:03,13
C1,C2,2014-06-30 17:49:59,2014-07-01 02:46:20,11,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 18:16:51,2014-07-01 06:15:25,20,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 18:18:07,N,N,2014-07-01 00:02:22,24
C1,C2,2014-06-30 18:41:27,N,N,N,N
```

Can anyone provide a sed/awk way to achieve this? I want to use sed/awk in the future work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hey @haifzhan, even when sed appears to be doing something "in-place", it's actually not http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed#In-place_editing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This statement removes the last two columns, where `sample.csv` is the name of the input file.

```
sed s/,[^,]*,[^,]*$//g sample.csv
```

My result was:

```
C1,C2,2014-06-30 13:11:46,2014-07-01 00:19:12,43,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 13:37:40,N,N,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 15:35:40,2014-07-01 00:23:14,36,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 16:54:07,2014-07-01 00:08:38,35,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 17:13:33,N,N,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 17:23:05,N,N,2014-07-01 00:26:03,13
C1,C2,2014-06-30 17:49:59,2014-07-01 02:46:20,11,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 18:16:51,2014-07-01 06:15:25,20,N,N
C1,C2,2014-06-30 18:18:07,N,N,2014-07-01 00:02:22,24
C1,C2,2014-06-30 18:41:27,N,N,N,N
```

In your example, you deleted the last 3 columns, you could do that by modifying the original statement to be the following:

```
sed s/,[^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*$//g sample.csv
```

Comment: Hi Adam, I found that and modified my python script, thanks. Can you explain more about your sed script? why is it  comma, then not ma, then any characters, then comma, then ...

Comment: oh, i got it. you use regex to find out the comma+last two columns, thanks !

Comment: Exactly. I find the comma, then `[^,]*` means 'any number of characters that are not a comma'. So I find a comma, then a bunch of non-commas, then another comma, then non-commas. Finally `$` means a line break.

Answer (score 4):

Awk solution

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NF=(NF-2)' file
```

Comment: This is so rad, I didn't know awk could do that!  As a note, you might also want to make it awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=","}NF=(NF-2)' so that awk doesn't print whitespace as the delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

cut is definitely the easiest tool to achieve this:

```
cat input | cut -d, -f8,9 --complement
```

Note that the osx version of cut is outdated, so it's best to fetch the latest:

```
brew install coreutils
```

Comment: thanks, can it modify all files directly, i mentioned in the question that I had around 120 files(generate a file daily, around 4 month)